# Jersey restful web service on grizzly server, client javascript

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, grizzly

i'm new with web service programming and i want to create,using netbeans 6, a restful web service using Jersey over a Grizzly server and then a client javascript in order to use this web service through a browser. So i started learning more on restful web service and i read a lot of guide over the web, then i started learning more on grizzly and jersey by reading jersey user's guide http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/index.html. I succesfully follow the tutorial to create the helloword example resource. So i created all the resources needed for the job and tested successfully with the browser...but i'm still confused: in particular i want know how i can create a static homepage which can be used by the users to select what is the desired resource. Can you give me some tutorial or example?? Thanks to all!

(Moreover i want to learn more on grizzly server and creating jersey restful web service, can someone give me a useful guide or book??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the key to understanding RESTful web services is to understand the HTTP protocol more thoroughly.  That's what makes it easier than (and often preferable to) RPC style services epitomized by SOAP.  When you pull down a static web page, for example, you can think of it as a limited "web service" which serves only GET requests.  In order to make a static web page which "selects resources," you would only need to provide URLs to the resources in question, as long as they're accessed via GET, because that's the same HTTP method used for retrieving web pages (and therefore is the default method for web browsers).  If you want to access other types of resources, such as sending POST requests, you can use a form; other than that (with PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, etc.) you'll want to use Javascript or a more programmatic API for accessing the HTTP resources.

There are many good books in this space, and I've found these particularly useful:

- [*RESTful Web Services*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260)
- [*RESTful Web Services Cookbook*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596801688)
- [*RESTful Java with Jax-RS*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596158041)
- [*SOA With REST*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137012519)

The first two approach REST in theory and practice; they are more about the concepts than specific technology.  The third addresses the Java standard for RESTful services as defined in [JSR 311](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311), of which Jersey is the reference implementation.
The last is more of an "enterprisey" book, but it's been useful to me from the approach of designing a *system* of web services, as opposed to one-off service resources.

Comment: thank you!! i'm reading RESTful JAVA with Jax-RS and trying to learn more on HTTP protocol.

Comment: Great! Would you mind "accepting" my answer if you found it useful?

Comment: I ask you another question that is not clear to me, i want to have an index.html static page as the first page when a user make a request...reading this book there is in chapter 3 some explanation of this (also in an example at the end of the book) but i don't understand very well....can you help me??? thank you!!

Comment: You should probably ask that as a separate question, with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Grizzly you can take a look at Grizzly User's Guide, specifically [Http Server framework](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/docbkx2.2/html/http-server-framework.html) chapter. If you have more questions don't hesitate to ask on Grizzly [mailing lists](http://grizzly.java.net/communicate.html).

Comment: Hi, i readed this guide and you'r right it's very useful, now i subscribed the mailing list as you suggested. I'm trying to create my first grizzly web server and i read few articles about Comet...if i understood well, comet act in a similar way to suspend a request, in order to send more than one response (by the server), but it's "event driven" and the event can be just the push of a simple button by the user...so how can i integrate comet with a simple grizzly http web server?? do you know where i can read some about this?? Thank you very much!!!!!!